# How do I implement the email service for microsoft web robot

Tags: c#, azure, bots, botframework

I am trying to get the following lines into my project, in order to test the email feature of Microsoft Bot framework:

```
                List<ChannelAccount> participants = new List<ChannelAccount>();
                participants.Add(new ChannelAccount("shansari@verizon.net", "Shahin Ansari"));
                IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
                bool isGroup = false;
                ConversationParameters cpMessage = new ConversationParameters(message.Recipient, isGroup, participants, "Quarter End Discussion");
                var ConversationId = connector.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(cpMessage);
                //message.From = botChannelAccount;
                message.From = new ChannelAccount();
                message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount();

                message.ChannelId = "email";

                message.Text = "Hey, what's up everyone?";

                message.Locale = "en-Us";

                connector.Conversations.SendToConversation((Activity)message);
                //await connector.Conversations.SendToConversation((Activity)message);
                var replyMessage = activity.CreateReply("Yo, I heard you Sean.", "en");
                connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(replyMessage);
```

But I receive no email.

I know that the "print" statement that sends the 'Yo, I heard you Sean' does work when I put it at the top. But it does not when it is at the bottom. So something breaks in those few lines. But I don't know how to troubleshoot this when I pushed it to Azure, and debugging it locally won't get me much since it seems to compile just fine. Has anyone does this before?

I think I made all the updates you suggested, and pushed to Azure yet no email is generated. Here is my updated code:

```
namespace Bot_Application1
{
    [BotAuthentication]
    public class MessagesController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// POST: api/Messages
        /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                // calculate something for us to return
                int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

                // return our reply to the user
                Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");
                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                var replyMessage = activity.CreateReply("Yo, I heard you Sean.", "en");
                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(replyMessage);

                // Start of my own code 
                //try { 
                // The code until the line above 
                List<ChannelAccount> participants = new List<ChannelAccount>();
                participants.Add(new ChannelAccount("shansari@verizon.net", "Shahin Ansari"));

                IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
                bool isGroup = false;
                ConversationParameters cpMessage = new ConversationParameters(message.Recipient, isGroup, participants, "Quarter End Discussion");
                var ConversationId = await connector.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(cpMessage);
                message.Recipient = new ChannelAccount("shansari@verizon.net", "Shahin Ansari");
                //message.From = new ChannelAccount("shansari@verizon.net", "Shahin Ansari");

                message.From = new ChannelAccount();
                //message.From = message.ChannelData;
                message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: ConversationId.Id);

                message.ChannelId = "email";

                message.Text = "Hey, what's up everyone?";

                message.Locale = "en-Us";

                connector.Conversations.SendToConversation((Activity)message);
                //await connector.Conversations.SendToConversation((Activity)message);

                //}
                //catch (Exception ex)
                //{
                //  Trace.TraceError("Sean's Exception: " + ex.ToString());
                // throw;
                //}
                //await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);

            }
            else
            {
                HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;

        }

        private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
        {
            if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
            {
                // Implement user deletion here
                // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
                // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
                // Not available in all channels
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle add/remove from contact lists
                // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
            {
                // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
            {
            }

            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue is you need to set the Conversation value in the message.  Also should probably also await on the async functions:

```
        List<ChannelAccount> participants = new List<ChannelAccount>();
        participants.Add(new ChannelAccount("shansari@verizon.net", "Shahin Ansari"));
        IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
        bool isGroup = false;
        ConversationParameters cpMessage = new ConversationParameters(message.Recipient, isGroup, participants, "Quarter End Discussion");
        var ConversationId = await connector.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(cpMessage);  
        //message.From = botChannelAccount;
        message.From = new ChannelAccount();
        message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount();

        message.ChannelId = "email";
```

> ```
>       message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: ConversationId.Id);
> ```

```
        message.Text = "Hey, what's up everyone?";

        message.Locale = "en-Us";

        connector.Conversations.SendToConversation((Activity)message);
        //await connector.Conversations.SendToConversation((Activity)message);
        var replyMessage = activity.CreateReply("Yo, I heard you Sean.", "en");
        await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(replyMessage);
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working. There are some things, which I need to fine tune, but the emails are being generated.